# Python re.search unicode parsing

Tags: python, unicode

I am new to python and I am having issues with a unicode string

Here is my string:  `u'3 hrs, 12 mins, 56 secs (11576 Seconds)'`

I am trying to pull out the number of seconds for use in another function. I was trying to use `re.search()` but was having difficulty.  Can someone please suggest a way to do this?

Thanks
C

Comment: You should show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u'3 hrs, 12 mins, 56 secs (11576 Seconds)'
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> m = literal_eval(re.search(r"\((\d+) Seconds\)", s).group(1))
>>> m
11576
```

Pattern = `r"\((\d+) Seconds\)"`

- ( - Checks for opening bracket "("'
- (\d+) - Checks for digits.
- Seconds - Static string content.
- ) - Checks for closing braket ")".

Answer (score 0):

Do `re.search(r'\d+ Seconds',myString)`, and then remove Seconds from the output using `output.replace(' Seconds','')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Unicode raw string (`ur'xxx'`) in your search expression, and grouping to pluck out the exact part you want (parentheses):

```
>>> import re
>>> s=u'3 hrs, 12 mins, 56 secs (11576 Seconds)'
>>> re.search(ur'(\d+) Seconds',s).group(1)
u'11576'
>>> int(re.search(ur'(\d+) Seconds',s).group(1))
11576
```